# Python generators and yield - increment to the next() call in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, generator, yield

In the code snippet below, how would you increment the `next()` call using an operator `+=` instead of typing `print(next(seq))` four times? With this in a `while` loop, only the first instance of `print(next(seq))` will print repeatedly. How do I advance to the next one with each iteration?

```
def get_sequence_upto(x):
    for i in range(x):
        yield i 

seq = get_sequence_upto(5)

print(next(seq))

print(next(seq))

print(next(seq))

print(next(seq))
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

edit: added the while loop snippet

```
while True:
seq = loop_here(x)

        print(next(seq))
```

I have tried adding += to different points within the code with no success.

Comment: `With this in a while loop, only the first instance of print(next(seq)) will print repeatedly` No it will not happen given that you did not put `seq = get_sequence_upto(5)` inside the while loop.

Comment: sorry the, the while loop code is  a little different, but the same concept.

Comment: please provide the code

Comment: I added the while loop part - thanks

Comment: please keep `seq = loop_here(x)` outside the while loop, you are reinitializing `seq` every iteration of the loop. Also it is better to use `For ... in` otherwise you have to handle the `StopIteration` exception with `try ... except`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `yield from` with a for loop:

```
def get_sequence_upto(x):
    yield from range(x)

nums = get_sequence_upto(5)
while True:
    x = next(nums, None)
    if x is not None:
        print(x)
        continue
    break
```

Or with `try` `except`:

```
def get_sequence_upto(x):
    yield from range(x)

nums = get_sequence_upto(5)
while True:
    try:
        print(next(nums))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! I realize I asked this question incorrectly - apologies, my question is on the while loop part. I edited the question.

Comment: @LeoOptimoII Edited my answer should work now

Comment: @LeoOptimoII Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use for loop like below:

```
def get_sequence_upto(x):
    for i in range(x):
        yield i 

seq = get_sequence_upto(5)
while seq:
    try:
        print(next(seq))
    except:
        break
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and answer - I realize I asked the question incorrectly - I edited the question to include the while loop part

Comment: @LeoOptimoII what do ypu need? need  while loop

Comment: I need the while loop - the for part is misleading. I will edit the question one more time. Thank YOU all.

Comment: @LeoOptimoII I edit my answer is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is - I realize that I asked the question incorrectly though.

Comment: Yes this also works, thanks a lot for your time. StackOverflow will only allow me to select only one answer tho :(

Comment: @LeoOptimoII OK but my answer is oldest answer and other answer is copy of my answer is not good `aceept` new answer always user when answer look like `accept` oldest answer